# Laravel 5.5 - How to link a blade.php to look for images in public folder

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I created a webpage in HTML with a ton of images. Now I need that page in my laravel project , I added the CSS and complied so its good. The problem is with images , how do I link my blade.php to look for the images in public/images folder.

I did some search and it shows add

```
src="{{ asset('images/background.jpg') }}"
```

instead of

```
src="images/background.jpg"
```

But my pages have a large number of images, is there a way I can link the blade.php to look for images in the public folder, like we do compile for CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has File Storage system. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

In controller, you can read list of files in specific directory and you have files list array. After, you can send this array list to view file.

In view file, you loop all files with foreach and give link them.

I recommend put this files in **storage** folder. Document clearly explain this.